# Rename package com.abb.acc to com.abb.acc.add

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to rename package name  from **com.abb.acc** to **com.abb.acc.add** (Android Studio).

Right click ----> New -----> Package, it create folder out side the file

expecting get result like - package **com.abb.acc.add**

Comment: Just drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, you want to change file from package **com.abb.acc** to **com.abb.acc.add**, then just change the package line on top(in the file) to `package com.abb.acc.add`. Then press alt-enter and select `move to package 'com.abb.acc.add'`.

If you want to rename your entire package, then right-click on your package, select Refactor -> Rename...

Comment: My current package name is com.abb.acc want rename with one extra name eg:-com.abb.acc.add / com.bdas.vggh.kuuu

Comment: If you want to rename your entire package, then right click on your package, select Refactor -> Rename...

Comment: @ChrisvinJem It doesn't work that way. If you go into Finder (or Explorer for Windows) and navigate to your project and open /app/src/main/java each part of the package (when divided by the dots) will be a folder, containing the next part in it.

Comment: Wait, why are you trying to rename your package from Finder instead of from Android Studio?

Comment: No. What I mean is that it doesn't work that way, @ChrisvinJem to rename the entire package you have to rename each part of the package. See for yourself. Find your project and navigate to where the package is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Right click com ----> new ----> package,  enter new package name without **com**

Right click previous package name > Refactor > move to new package

Move package com.app to another package

Then delete the old package

I have solved by this way

Comment: This won't refactor the package names in the code though, will it? Why not just refactor from Android Studio, any particular reasons?